# How to parse html source code with ruby/nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I've successfully used ruby (1.8) and nokogiri's css parsing to pull out front facing data from web pages.

However I now need to pull out some data from a series of pages where the data is in the "meta" tags in the source code of the page.

One of the lines I need is the following:

```
<meta name="geo.position" content="35.667459;139.706256" />
```

I've tried using xpath put haven't been able to get it right.

Any help as to what syntax is needed would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You say "I've tried using xpath put haven't been able to get it right."  **Show us what you have tried** so that we can help you do it right.

Comment: Thx Andy - just various ways of saying '//meta[blah]' etc. I just couldn't get the syntax correct to pull it out. I really wanted to do it with the css selector and now I know how.

Comment: Use https://github.com/BorisBresciani/rails_parse_head

Answer (score 2):

This is a good case for a [CSS attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors). For example:

```
doc.css('meta[name="geo.position"]').each do |meta_tag|
  puts meta_tag['content'] # => 35.667459;139.706256
end
```

The equivalent XPath expression is almost identical:

```
doc.xpath('//meta[@name = "geo.position"]').each do |meta_tag|
  puts meta_tag['content'] # => 35.667459;139.706256
end
```

Comment: Wow thanks I had no idea you could use the css selector for meta tags too.

If I wanted to get the lat/long from the js does the same apply?
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function onLoad() {   
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    var point1 = new GLatLng(35.667459, 139.706256);
    map.setCenter(point1, 15, G_NORMAL_MAP);
    var marker = new GMarker(point1,{clickable:false});
    map.addOverlay(marker);
    }
    }
    //]]>
    </script>

Comment: No, Nokogiri doesn't do Javascript. You could extract the Javascript from the HTML using Nokogiri, then use a regex to get the lat/long. `    doc.at('script').content[/GLatLng\\(([^)]+)\\)/,1] # => "35.667459, 139.706256"` for instance.

Comment: Aha okay awesome thanks very much for your help - that has really made things much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<meta name="geo.position" content="35.667459;139.706256" />')
doc.at('//meta[@name="geo.position"]')['content'] # => "35.667459;139.706256"
```